# How to validate Multiple text field in ios

Tags: ios

I am working on application ,that contains multiple TextFields,Is there any way to validate all the field at once to check they all are not empty before submitting.as i able to validate one by one.

Comment: Do you want to check them for empty when you tap a button? Or something like that? and show us the code you've tried so far..

Comment: Might be There is no any code that check validation of all the textField at one time/once  to check they all are not empty .. you need to do it separately :)

Comment: No! you have to check it one by one! if there is any code which simultaneously check all the field. It will be checking it one by one all of them at back end.

Comment: As Mentioned in the comments,I can't validate all the fields at once ,i have to iterate through all the fields.i did exactly as **@svrushal** Mentioned.Before this i am validating all the fields with simple if conditions,there is about 59 textfield in the form with other controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *viewsToRemove = [self.view subviews];
for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove)
{
    if([v isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        UITextField *txt=(UITextField *)v;
        //check for spaces
        NSString *str=[txt.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet
        if([str length]<=0)
        {
            //raise the error
            //To raise the proper error, check for the tag by assigning tag to each textfield in xib.
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure the logic will not slow your application.
Otherwise to the validation one by one...

Answer (score 1):

If you using a storyboard/xib file then connect all textfields to an IBOutletCollection instead of connecting each textfield to different IBOutlets. The IBOutletCollection give an array of textfields, so you can use an enumeration for validation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one
In the below code u find all the textfeilds in your view and then check whether it is blank or nil.

```
- (IBAction)SubmitTapped:(id)sender {

    for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)view;
            if([textField.text length]==0){
                NSLog(@"Please fill...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are checking for the @"", which will not work if user enter space in the text field

Comment: @svrushal Thanks for pointing out the mistake, i have changed the code now.

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet worked for me :

```
    // Get the subviews of the view
    NSArray *listOfSubviews = [self.view subviews];

    // Return if there are no subviews
    if ([listOfSubviews count] == 0) return;

    for (UIView *view in listOfSubviews) {

        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) { // Check for UITextField view

             UITextField *txtTextField = (UITextField *) view;

            if ((txtTextField.text.length != 0) || [txtTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
                // textfield is empty
            }
            else {
                // textfield is not empty
            }
        }
    }
```